# Adding score together from database

Tags: java, android, database

I've made an app that tracks how well someone drives, it gives people a score at the end of their journey

I want to show their average score adding together all of their scores which are stored on a database. At the moment the score displays but I cant work out how to add them together, heres the database method

```
  public Cursor getJourneyScore(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM userJourney ", null);
    return  data;
}
```

This gets all of the journey details and then in the main method it gets the score and displays it like this:

```
 Cursor res = dbHelper2.getJourneyScore();
    if (res.getCount() == 0) {
        showMessageData("Error", "No data");
        return;
    }
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        buffer.append(res.getString(2));
        buffer.append("+");
    }
    String string = buffer.toString();

    scoreTxt.setText(string);
```

It displays each of the scores like this "877+858+" if there was two journeys completed.

How could i get the scores from the database and automatically add them together and the app do this as more journeys and scores are added?

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out, I had to format the code correctly like this

```
    String scores[] = string.split("\\s+");
    int calc = 0;
    for (String number : scores) {
        Integer n = Integer.parseInt(number);
        calc += n;
    }

    int averageScore = calc / journey_counts;
```